# DomainContext with RIA Service losing List entries after SubmitChanges

Tags: wcf, silverlight, ria

I am calling SubmitChanges to submit changes to one of my RIA entities.  This entity has a property that has a property which is an ObservableCollection of Items.

The only change I have made is I have added an entry to this list.

When I check the count property before calling Submit changes it is the correct count.  Let's say 6.
After calling SubmitChanges, the count on the client side is 1.  And the list only contains the newly added item and not the previously existing items.

On the server, the operation indicates that all 6 items are there, and I have used Fiddler to verify that all 6 items are being returned back to my client.

However, in the next line of code to run in the application the count of this list is 1 (or the number of newly added items).

I have verified that all the items are there properly and that when I create a new DomainContext and have the data reloaded all of the items in the list are there, even the ones that I added.

Any thoughts on what could cause this behaviour?  These items are getting lost somewhere.

Here is the object in question along with the ObservableCollection that is losing it's entries.

```
[DataContract(Name = "CT", Namespace = "http://domain/properties")]
public class ChoicePropertyType : PropertyType
{
    [DataMember(Name = "C")]
    public bool IsCustomValueAllowed { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "A")]
    public bool AllowMultiple { get; set; }        

    private ObservableCollection<ValidValue> _defaultValues;

          [Association("DefaultValues", "Id", "ParentId")]
    [Include]
    [Composition]
    [DataMember(Name = "D")]
    public ObservableCollection<ValidValue> DefaultValues
    {
        get
        {
            if (_defaultValues == null)
                _defaultValues = new ObservableCollection<ValidValue>();
            return _defaultValues;
        }
    }

}

[KnownType(typeof(ChoicePropertyType))]
[KnownType(typeof(DatePropertyType))]
[KnownType(typeof(NumberPropertyType))]
[KnownType(typeof(TextPropertyType))]
[KnownType(typeof(UserPropertyType))]
[DataContract(Name = "PT", Namespace = "http://domain/properties")]
public class PropertyType
{
    [Key]
    [DataMember(Name = "I")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "P")]
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "R")]
    public bool IsRequired { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "H")]
    public bool HasDefaultValue { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I was wondering if you could perhaps share some of the code?

Comment: Ok, I provided a code sample of the object in question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the metadata of the RIA Entity needs to have an [Include] attribute decorating the list property. Furthermore, if that List represents other entities it should really be an EntityCollection.

One issue with the include is that any time you query the Ria Entity, the related items in the list (all of them) will also be returned. If however the Include is not used, you need to load those related items in the domain context first via separate Load call.

That means you need to execute a query that will load all the related items in the list in the domain context, and then your ria entity will have the proper reltionships with the items in the list.

Furthermore, adding an item to the list of the ria entity is not really the right way to go about doing this. First you'd add the ria entity to the context if it isn't there already. Then you would add the related entity to the context. Finally you would tie the two together via the related entity's ria entity link and save changes.

example:

add or retrieve ria entity to domain context.
create related entity 
related entity.ria entity referential link = ria entity;
add related entity to context.
save changes.

Comment: I am not sure if this applies.  In truth, the List was indeed an ObservableCollection already.  Can you see anything in the code that might need to be changed?

Comment: Is ChoicePropertyType inheriting from an entity? Ria Entity?

Comment: It's inheriting from PropertyType which is a regular class with a DataContract attribute decorating the class.  What is special about a RIA Entiy?

Comment: If I understand how RIA works correctly.  On the client the generated proxy for the object would be a RIA Entity.  On the server, it's a regular class - as I have shown in the code sample.